Is the only spherically symmetric harmonic function $\frac{1}{r}$?
Given any function $f$ in 3 dimensions, $f$ is harmonic if $\nabla^2f=0$ and is spherically symmetric if $\partial_\theta f=\partial_\phi f=0$, so a function $f$ is spherically symmetric and harmonic if $\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_r f)=0$ by the definition of the Laplacian $\nabla^2$ in spherical coordinates.
This seems to directly imply that any spherically symmetric harmonic function must be of the form $f=\frac{a}{r}+b$ for constants $a$ and $b$. The way I see it, $\frac{c}{r^2}\neq0$ for any $c$, so $\partial_r (r^2\partial_r f)$ must be zero, which means that $r^2\partial_r f$ must be a constant, which means $\partial_r f=\frac{d}{r^2}$ for some $d$, and taking the antiderivative this seems to imply that $f=\frac{a}{r}+b$ (note that the derivative of that function is $\partial_r f=-\frac{a}{r^2}$, so $r^2\partial_r f=-a$ and $\partial_r(r^2\partial_r f)=0$ making $f$ harmonic).
My question is are there any other spherically symmetric harmonics, i.e. are there other functions $g$ dependent only on $r$ which satisfy the radial harmonic equation $\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_rg)=0$? This simple analysis says that the only such functions are of the form $\frac{a}{r}+b$ but my intuition wants to say that there are others; that feels too simple a result, unless my intuition is mistaken.

Your intuition is wrong, there are no other spherically symmetric harmonic functions. Why don't you believe your own proof?

Your intuition simply does not match the facts you presented, and facts win out. Only $f(r)=a/r+b$ is both spherically symmetric in three-dimensional space and harmonic.
In fact all spherical harmonic functions have restricted forms. We requird the following conditions:

The variation in $\phi$, if such exists, must be periodic with period equal to $2\pi$ divided by a whole number.

The variation in $\theta$ must be a combination of trigonometric functions that has zero slope at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$. This is needed to have a continuous differentiable function as we go through the "poles" of the coordinate system.

We then have a discrete set of functions in $\theta$ and $\phi$. Each one sets a requirement on the function of$r$ to finally derive the complete harmonic function. Formulas for the allowed functions meeting all the constraints can be found at many sources such as Wolfram Mathworld.


